# penup() first time through for loop

Tags: python, loops, python-turtle

I'm trying to get Python's Turtle graphics to plot a series of calculated `x` and `y` values based on the formulas below.  All the calculations work, but I only want the pen down starting at the first calculated `(x, y)` point, not at the origin.  My idea was to check when `i = 0` (the first time through the `for` loop) and raise the pen before going to the first calculated `(x, y)` point.  After that, when `i` is larger than 0, the pen would be down and a line would be drawn to the next calculated `(x, y)` point.  I'm sure there's a simple to fix to my code, but I can't spot it.  Maybe someone (everyone???) can point me to the error(s)???  Thanks!

```py
penup()

for i in range(20000):
    speed(10)

    x1 = 200*sin(f1*t + p1)*e**(-t*d1) + 200*sin(f2*t + p2)*e**(-t*d2)
    y1 = 200*sin(f3*t + p3)*e**(-t*d3) + 200*sin(f4*t + p4)*e**(-t*d4)
    setpos(x1,y1)
    pendown()
 
    t += dt
```

Comment: You could put `turtle.up()` before the loop, then inside the loop put `setpos(x1, y1)` followed by `turtle.down()`.

Comment: It'a also fairly common to check the loop variable as you have done. Or set an 'initialized' flag to False before you start, then inside the loop, check that variable, do the initialization, then set it True.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  I can add penup() before the loop and I see the turtle moving as expected (with no lines drawn).  However, when I add pendown() after the setpos(x1,y1), the code fails.  This is how it looks now.

Comment: Your main code looks mostly OK, except `t += dt` should probably be indebted to put it inside the loop. I can't read the code pasted in your comment.

Comment: I edited my original code since new code in the comments didn't work.  I'll check into the location of the t += dt

Comment: I've re-entered the code that works.  Thanks for the help!